# Chart.js data structure, how can I dynamically fill this with an array and random colors?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm using chart.js to display a Doughnut chart on my site, I'd like to be able to populate the values in the chart dynamically with an array of content pulled from somewhere else on the page.  Chart.js stores it's values for the Doughnut chart in this data structure

```
var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: 10,
                color:"#F7464A"
            },
            {
                value : 10,
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },
            {
                value : 20,
                color : "#FDB45C"
            },
            {
                value : 50,
                color : "#949FB1"
            }

        ];
```

How can I populate the values of this data structure dynamically in Javascript?

I already know how I'm going to generate the random colors using this (for anyone interested)

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
```

Comment: Nice random hex one liner

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're going to have is that actual randomness isn't really perceived as random, so you're going to have to figure out a way to check the color similarity between each of these colors to make sure they don't appear to be indistinguishable. I've done this before with three colors (below). What I would suggest instead is creating a list of colors that you already know are dissimilar and randomly choosing from that list instead.

I tried to keep my colors within a certain range:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var color = '';
    while (!color.match(/(#[c-e].)([e-f][a-f])([9-c].)/)) {
        color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.pow(16,6))).toString(16);
    }
    return color;
}

function getColorSimilarityIndex(c1, c2) {
    var index = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 5) {
            if (c1.substring(i, i + 1) === c2.substring(i, i + 1)) {
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}

var color1 = getRandomColor();
var color2 = getRandomColor();
var color3 = getRandomColor();

while (getColorSimilarityIndex(color2, color1) > 0) {
    color2 = getRandomColor();
}
while (getColorSimilarityIndex(color3, color1) > 0 || getColorSimilarityIndex(color3, color2) > 0) {
    color3 = getRandomColor();
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `getColorSimilarityIndex` works by checking if the "tens" place (second octet place?) value of Red or Blue is the same, it returns greater than 0.  Any reasoning behind that?

Comment: @Thymine "I tried to keep my colors within a certain range" -- for what I was doing, I wanted my color scheme to be predominantly green/yellow, so I confined the green regexp to a pretty small range, but allowed a relatively wider range for the red component, and an even wider range for the blue component so that they would potentially generate recognizably different colors. Then the similarity index was really only concerned with enforcing that the red and blue components were different enough. I determined that the 10's place should be at least a single digit apart for that to be true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the array with the appropriate elements in it like the below:

```
var getcolor = function (num) {
    if (num == 0)
        return "#F38630";
    if (num == 1)
        return "#E0E4CC";
    if (num == 2)
        return "#69D2E7";
    if (num == 3)
        return "#003399";
    if (num == 4)
        return "#969696";
};

var piedata = []
for (i = 0; i <= self.countViolationsByManager().length - 1; i++) {
    piedata.push({
        value: self.countViolationsByManager()[i].Count(),
        label: self.countViolationsByManager()[i].MoneyManagerName(),
        color: getcolor(i)
    });
}

var pieoptions = {
}
var ctx = $("#myPieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata, pieoptions);
```